# Cosmos db REST API order by with partitioning

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the REST API with SQL for Cosmos db and need to return a query's results ordered by a timestamp (which is stored as UNIX numeric timestamp). I'm trying to do this with a simple ORDER BY.

```
e.g. SELECT * FROM requests c ORDER BY c.timestamp
```

However with partitioning I get the error:

> "Cross partition query with TOP/ORDER BY or aggregate functions is not
>   supported."

In the collection settings the indexing precision for strings is set to -1, which was a suggestion from elsewhere, however the error is still thrown.

If I remove or set to false the x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition header then I get:

> "Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set
>   x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify
>   x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this
>   exception."

Has anyone had any success doing this via the SQL REST API?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you disable cross partition query, the error is saying that you cannot use OrderBy with it enabled

Comment: If I disable cross partition query then I get: "Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception."

Comment: Is this a very old collection? This used to be an issue before they added support for Order by and Top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

However , based on this official [statement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cross-partition-order-by-queries-now-available-in-documentdb-java-and-node-js-sdks/), `java` sdk and `node.js` sdk are support for `TOP` and `ORDER BY` queries on partitioned collections. I test the same query via sdk and it works.

[image]

---

***Update Answer:***

I used the `Flidder` tool to observe the requests from the SDK, and I found three requests included.

***One:***

When I run the above sdk code, the first request as below and the exactly the same error that rest received. However , sdk will do retry for me to get the `_rid` property of partition.

[image]

***Two:***

[image]

I did not find any clear official explanation about this.However , after reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#partitioning-in-azure-cosmos-db), I suppose the cross partition here refers to physical partitions , not logical partitions. So the request help us to get the "rid" of the physical partition which your data stored in and `PartitionKeyRanges`.

***Three:***

[image]

Then sdk send update request for me with additional property :`x-ms-documentdb-partitionkeyrangeid`. And query results returned correctly. Please notice the update sql in the last request.

I think you could emulate the requests SDK did for us to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it looks like the SDKs support this somehow but the direct SQL API doesn't, which is annoying if you are using a language that doesn't have a SDK written for it.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. I've replicated that in code and it works for order by and top.

For anyone else who finds this in the future: to use to /pkranges URL your authorization header needs to use "pkranges" as the resource type.

Comment: Thanks! It seems weird, that this is not officially documented. Altough it seems kinda hacky.

Comment: This just saved me a bunch of re-work. Thank you. Frustrating this isn't automated or documented via the REST API! @chris-anderson-msft

The whole world don't use SDK's or common platforms.