# Unable to order by data in Azure Cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Following is the error message we got:

> Expecting string but got No value. cannot execute cross partition order by queries  on mixed types.

This is working for me

```sql
Select * from c
Order by date desc
```

But not this

```sql
Select * 
From c
Order by date asc
```

How can we order by data in Azure cosmos db

Comment: I'm using python SDK. But I'm getting same error in Azure data explorer also.

Comment: Partition key is id which is string. Example " 1234567890.2637488495994"

Comment: That query is not working for me. Intially it was working. I think partition key might be the problem. Earlier key was alphanumeric string.

Comment: @Adataguy - please edit your question to show some sample data, along with the exact way you're executing your query (e.g. your python code). Currently, you've only provided a query with no other details.

Comment: Also: you have a typo in your query (`order by date`) - you need to include the alias `c` (e.g. `order by c.date`). As for the error message: it's mentioning mixed types - so, do you have different data types in the `date` property, across different documents?

Comment: For some documents that field is missing. Is this could be a concern ?

Comment: My major concern is descending order by is working  but ascending isn't working

Comment: Refer below two links. It may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240232/cosmos-db-rest-api-order-by-with-partitioning
 https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/733